# Filtrar por atributo un XML a una tabla hecha con XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Tengo que realizar una tabla con xslt desde un xml filtrando por el atributo "type", en este caso quiero que salgan los tipados con 'vegetable', me sale la tabla pero nada de info de esos casos.

```
    <food_list>
    <food_item type="vegetable">
        <name>Agar</name>
        <carbs_per_serving>81</carbs_per_serving>
        <fiber_per_serving>8</fiber_per_serving>
        <fat_per_serving>0.5</fat_per_serving>
        <kj_per_serving>1280</kj_per_serving>
    </food_item>
    
    <food_item type="fruit">
        <name>Kiwi Fruit</name>
        <carbs_per_serving>7.5</carbs_per_serving>
        <fiber_per_serving>2.5</fiber_per_serving>
        <fat_per_serving>0</fat_per_serving>
        <kj_per_serving>150</kj_per_serving>
    </food_item>
   
    
    <food_item type="grain">
        <name>Wheatgerm</name>
        <carbs_per_serving>1.5</carbs_per_serving>
        <fiber_per_serving>1</fiber_per_serving>
        <fat_per_serving>0.5</fat_per_serving>
        <kj_per_serving>70</kj_per_serving>
    </food_item>
</food_list>
```

Este es el xslt que estoy intentando realizar. Sólo se me queda con el 'th', no me sale nada de información debajo. He intentado filtrar cada uno por el atributo 'vegetable' pero no me coge nada, ni el name, ni carbs, nada.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="yellow">
                        <th>Food Item</th>
                        <th>Carbs (g)</th>
                        <th>Fiber (g)</th>
                        <th>Fat (g)</th>
                        <th>Energy (kj)</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="food_list/food_item[type= 'vegetable']">
                        <tr bgcolor="lightgreen">
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="carbs_per_serving"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="fiber_per_serving"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="fat_per_serving"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="kj_per_serving"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A ver si podéis echarme algún cable, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de `<xsl:for-each select="food_list/food_item[type= 'vegetable']">` necesitas `<xsl:for-each select="food_list/food_item[@type= 'vegetable']">`, es decir, en tu intento original con la expresión `type = 'vegetable'` faltaba el sufijo `@` en frente de `type` para seleccionar el atributo de ese nombre (sin `@` la expresión selecciona un elemento).

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar un poco el porque eso lo soluciona?  Lo digo porque esta respuesta está calificada como de baja calidad por la falta de explicación justamente. Gracias!